# How I add security header on the front-end on Craft CMS

Tags: craft2, security

I have Mod_headers installed and active on my server, I know that Craft adds some headers from PHP but only for Control Panel requests. How can I add security headers to the front-end?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned `mod_headers`, you can add headers at the web-server level using `.htaccess` and Apache's `header set` command: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html